# com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the worksheets from a com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry.

The authentication works:

```
    GoogleCredential credential = authorize();
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("My Project");
    service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

I can get the spreadsheet entries:

```
    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL( "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
```

But as soon as I call the spreadsheet.getWorksheets() method I get the following error:

com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Unauthorized

My authorize method looks like this:

```
    File p12 = new File("src/main/resources/My Project-e81707237c5b.p12");
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    String [] SCOPESArray= {
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"
    };
    final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("727225752132-rnjnr63tk6ause0b2lotepig0mao837p@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing two service account scopes. Here are the required scopes:

```
    String [] SCOPESArray= {
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full",
            "https://docs.google.com/feeds"
    };
```